# Touch position not properly updated in Touch Gestures in windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, touch, gesture

I have implemented a control with name SimpleControl. In this control, I have implemented the touch support using the touch gestures. In this touch position is not properly updated while doing the touch panning operation. When doing the panning in horizontal or vertical directions its working fine. But when start the panning in vertical and then move the finger in horizontal direct the x position is not properly changed, it takes more time to update. So can you please suggest any ways to solve this problem?

In below sample, when do the touch panning the touch points are updates in output windows.

Replication procedure :
1. Run the sample
2. Start panning in vertical, find the positions are updated in output window
3. Then continue the panning in horizontal, the x position will change after position changed only.

Please find the sample from below,

[Sample Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_zLR5W_gJhDQ2ZkaUxUTHV3azQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this. when set the below code to gesture configuration the diagonal panning operation working fine and also the position updating problem as been solved.

```
GESTURECONFIG gc = new GESTURECONFIG();
                    gc.dwID = GID_PAN;
                    gc.dwWant = GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_VERTICALLY | GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_HORIZONTALLY | GC_PAN_WITH_INTERTIA;
                    gc.dwBlock = GC_PAN_WITH_GUTTER;
                    bool bResult = SetGestureConfig(
                        Handle, 
                        0,      
                        1,      
                        ref gc, 
                        _gestureConfigSize
                    );
```